# Cannot save value from target back to source. BindingExpression:Path=IsDropDownOpen; NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I'm creating a WPF application and I've hit a problem with combo boxes and a NullReferenceException being thrown.

In my application I have a view which along with some other things contains two combo boxes. The value chosen in the first combo box affects the options available in the second. For example...

Xaml...

```
<!-- language: xaml -->
<Label Name="FavoriteFoodLbl" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="13">Favorite Food</Label>
<ComboBox Name="FavoriteFoodCombo" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="13" ItemsSource="{Binding Foods}" SelectedItem="{Binding FavoriteFood, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

<Label Name="FavoriteFlavourLbl" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="13">Favorite Flavour</Label>
<ComboBox Name="FavoriteFlavourCombo" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="13" ItemsSource="{Binding Flavours}"  />
```

Extract from view model code...
    public ObservableCollection Foods { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection() { "Pizza", "Ice Cream", "Soup" };

```
    private string _favoriteFood;
    public string FavoriteFood
    {
        get { return _favoriteFood; }
        set
        {
            _favoriteFood = value;
            switch (_favoriteFood)
            {
                case "Pizza":
                    _flavours = new ObservableCollection<string>(PizzaToppings);
                    break;
                case "Ice Cream":
                    _flavours = new ObservableCollection<string>(IceCreamFlavours);
                    break;
                case "Soup":
                    _flavours = new ObservableCollection<string>(SoupFlavours);
                    break;
                default:
                    _flavours = new ObservableCollection<string>();
                    break;
            }
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FavoriteFood"));
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Flavours"));
        }
    }

    public List<string> PizzaToppings { get; set; } = new List<string>() { "Margarita", "Pepperoni", "Meat Feast" };
    public List<string> IceCreamFlavours { get; set; } = new List<string>() { "Vanilla", "Strawberry", "Chocolate" };
    public List<string> SoupFlavours { get; set; } = new List<string>() { "Tomato", "Leek and Potato", "Chicken" };

    private ObservableCollection<string> _flavours = null;
    public ObservableCollection<string> Flavours
    {
        get
        {
            return _flavours;
        }
        set
        {
            _flavours = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public string FavoriteFlavour { get; set; }
```

The problem only occurs when the user selects the value in the second combo box by typing (rather than via a mouse click).
Steps to reproduce:

1. Select a favorite food e.g. pizza
2. Use the tab key to move to the second combo
3. Press the first letter of a known option e.g. press 'P' for "Pepperoni"
4. Press another letter for which there are no options starting with it i.e. press 'e', as if you were still typing "Pepperoni"
5. Now choose a different favorite food e.g. Ice Cream. The value "Pepperoni" should disappear from the second box.
6. Now with the mouse, try to choose a favorite flavour of ice cream.

At this point I get an exception being thrown...

```
    Activated   Event   Time    Duration    Thread
Cannot save value from target back to source. BindingExpression:Path=IsDropDownOpen; DataItem='ComboBox' (Name=''); target element is 'ToggleButton' (Name='toggleButton'); target property is 'IsChecked' (type 'Nullable`1') NullReferenceException:'System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   at System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox.CoerceIsSelectionBoxHighlighted(Object o, Object value)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.ProcessCoerceValue(DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EntryIndex& entryIndex, Int32& targetIndex, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& oldEntry, Object& oldValue, Object baseValue, Object controlValue, CoerceValueCallback coerceValueCallback, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, Boolean skipBaseValueChecks)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.CoerceValue(DependencyProperty dp)
at System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox.OnIsDropDownOpenChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.SetValue(Object item, Object value)
at MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.UpdateValue(Object value)
at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.UpdateSource(Object value)'    869.72s
```

Anybody have any suggestions?

**Edit (06/12/2016 9:30)**
At the suggestion of James from the Material Design Toolkit, I have tried this in a separate project *without* the Material Design Toolkit and it's still a problem. I now feel a bit silly for not eliminating this earlier myself.
I'm removing the material-design-in-xaml tag.

I have uploaded a sample to github: https://github.com/DanMcCoy/ComboBoxBugDemo
This sample uses framework 4.6.1. I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 (14.0.25425.01 Update 3).

There's a video in the GitHub repo demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I'm can't seem to reproduce your issue. What framework and VS version are you using (I recall there were some bugs in 4.0 framework concerning ComboBox)? What implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged? Are your ComboBoxes styled?

Comment: Hi, james from Material Design in XAML here.  If this works WITHOUT the material design styles applied (and this is a definitely a MD issue), please post an issue on the GitHub project along with a demo repo, and I will take a look.

Comment: @James Willock - Sorry James. This doesn't appear to be a problem with the toolkit. Thank you for pointing out what _should_ have been an **obvious** thing to check.

Comment: @DanMcCoy cool. 

Comment: @DanMcCoy have you found a solution to this? I have the same issue. I've tested it in a few configurations.  The problem doesn't occur before .NET 4.0

Comment: My case is a little different, but I get the same exception.  Select an item in combobox #1 using the mouse -> click combobox #2 and select an item using the keyboard -> select another item still using the keyboard -> select an item from combobox #1 with the mouse -> click combobox #2 -> exception

Comment: @MrZander Sorry no. I can't actually remember what we did in the end. I think we may have changed the UI. I don't work there any more.

Comment: @DanMcCoy  Ahh darn, we are working around it in a not-so-desirable way by catching the exception.  However, for future reference to anyone else, this is fixed in .NET 4.6  (which my project can't move to yet...)